# Problema de Replace no sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

Tenho um campo na pagina que recebe somente numero, mais quando vou compara na função este valor da página com o que esta no banco, não retorna a pesquisar.

Estou tentando usar o `Replace` para tira o formatação do valor do banco para compara com o valor vindo da pagina.
este e o código que estou usando

```
IF @charLinhaDigitavel IS NOT NULL   
            BEGIN                              
                SET @SQL = @SQL + @CONDICAO + 'TIT.LinhaDigitavel LIKE ''%''+'+ '''' +replace( @charLinhaDigitavel,''.'',''''),replace( @charLinhaDigitavel,'' '','''' + '''' +'+''%'' '
                SET @CONDICAO = ' AND '   
            END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A princípio está faltando um `)` no último `replace`, seria algo como

```
replace( @charLinhaDigitavel,'' '','''') + '''' +'+''%'' '
```

Da maneira que está ai você acaba repetindo a linha digitável, já que você esta concatenando o resultado de um `replace` com o resultado de ouro `replace` (separados), aplicados na mesma variável. Tente utilizar um `replace` dentro do outro.

Por exemplo:

```
replace(replace(@charLinhaDigitavel,'' '','''' + ''''),''.'','''')
```

Dessa forma você irá aplicar sempre pegar o resultado do `replace` mais "interno" e aplicar o `replace` mais "externo".

Comment: Obrigado pela ajudar, mais analisando melhor o que postei, esta dando replace no lugar, pois o valor deste campo esta sendo preenchido da pagina e na pagina já foi tratado para aceitar somente numero, o replace, eu tinha que dar no valor que vinha do banco, no caso "TIT.LinhaDigitavel", e eu usei o replace encadeado no "TIT.LinhaDigitavel". `IF @charLinhaDigitavel IS NOT NULL BEGIN SET @SQL = @SQL + @CONDICAO + 'REPLACE(REPLACE(TIT.LinhaDigitavel,".","")," ","") LIKE ''%''+'+ '''' + @charLinhaDigitavel + '''' +'+''%'' ' SET @CONDICAO = ' AND ' END`

Comment: Espero que tenha ajudado a resolver seu problema =)